# VB.Net: slow Me.ShowInTaskBar

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, performance

I'm coding with VB.Net and .NET Framework 4.5.2

I added

```
Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
```

in a form with many controls and the opening time increased by 0.4-0.5 seconds.
I tried to move code in various places with no performance improvement.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Not the answer, but according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar(v=vs.110).aspx), the default value is `True`.  And you mean opening time increase 0.4 ~ 0.5 after add this line?

Comment: Would the user notice a 0.4-0.5 second delay?

Comment: It's entirely possible that changing that value after the form has already been loaded is causing a lot of the visual stuff to refresh. As others have said, this is the default value, so you don't need to set that. However, if you use the Properties tab for the form to set it, it will be put into the auto-generated code at the optimal place, and get executed before all of your other controls get loaded.

Comment: ShowInTaskbar is a very expensive property if the underlying window has already been created.  Winforms needs to pull a drastic trick to ensure that Explorer is aware of it, it needs to recreate the window to change the WS_EX_APPWINDOW style flag.  Many side-effects, you'll for example trigger a repaint if the window is already visible.  Also a good way to induce bugs, one nasty one is that the form disappears from the Application.OpenForms collection.  The code that assigns it belongs in the constructor (Sub New), never in the Load event handler.